# Codeigniter - How to extend two core classes

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm a noob in Codeigniter and PHP as well. 
I want to ask can I extend two classes from

> system/core/some_file

into

> application/core/MY_some_file?

I tried to make a custom exception error for some url that has disallowed character, so if there's a disallowed character there should be redirect to my custom controller.

Here's my custom core file (MY_URI):

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
class MY_URI extends CI_URI{

    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }
    function _filter_uri($str){
        if ($str != '' && $this->config->item('permitted_uri_chars') != '' && $this->config->item('enable_query_strings') == FALSE)
        {
            if ( ! preg_match("|^[".str_replace(array('\\-', '\-'), '-', preg_quote($this->config->item('permitted_uri_chars'), '-'))."]+$|i", $str))
            {
                $this->load->view('page_not_found_v');
            }
        }

        // Convert programatic characters to entities
        $bad    = array('$',        '(',        ')',        '%28',      '%29');
        $good   = array('&#36;',    '&#40;',    '&#41;',    '&#40;',    '&#41;');

        return str_replace($bad, $good, $str);
    }
}
```

I tried to load that view but it can't load it.

Answer (score 0):

It is an early point in the system workflow therefore you can't reach some objects yet.
But you can use custom error page:
Create a PHP file in the application/errors folder with name: error_400.php
for example with this content.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Error</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
    <h1><?php echo $heading; ?></h1>
    <?php echo $message; ?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

(but maybe you can copy the error_general.php and modify as you want).
Then in your overridden URI class you can display your custom page like this (instead of redirect):

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class MY_URI extends CI_URI {
    /**
     * Filter segments for malicious characters
     *
     * @access  private
     * @param   string
     * @return  string
     */
    function _filter_uri($str)
    {
        if ($str != '' && $this->config->item('permitted_uri_chars') != '' && $this->config->item('enable_query_strings') == FALSE)
        {
            // preg_quote() in PHP 5.3 escapes -, so the str_replace() and addition of - to preg_quote() is to maintain backwards
            // compatibility as many are unaware of how characters in the permitted_uri_chars will be parsed as a regex pattern
            if ( ! preg_match("|^[".str_replace(array('\\-', '\-'), '-', preg_quote($this->config->item('permitted_uri_chars'), '-'))."]+$|i", $str))
            {
                $_error =& load_class('Exceptions', 'core');
                echo $_error->show_error('The URI you submitted has disallowed characters.', 'The URI you submitted has disallowed characters.', 'error_400', 400);
                exit;
            }
        }

        // Convert programatic characters to entities
        $bad    = array('$',        '(',        ')',        '%28',      '%29');
        $good   = array('&#36;',    '&#40;',    '&#41;',    '&#40;',    '&#41;');

        return str_replace($bad, $good, $str);
    }
}
```

Th

Comment: for now the error can't access MY_URI files, it always load the message from URI.php in system/core

Comment: Now it's not that MY_URI doesn't loaded, but the error message doesn't appear as what I edited in MY_URI, and the error page that should be edited is in folder **view/error/html**